# Swift - extracting hours from NSDate, parsing string issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I receive a string in Json and first of all I have to do is to convert it into NSDate. The problem is, none of string formats I used is valid. the code goes as follows:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
var output = formatter.dateFromString("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(output)
```

as far as I know, if I want to retrieve hours from NSData, I have to call formatter once more

```
formatter.dateFormat = "hh"
```

and call it on NSDate obtained from string. Am I right?
My first question is: how to make the determine proper date format so the output will not be evaluated to nil? The second question is: Do I get it right or there is a simpler method or generally way to retrieve the hours from the following string: "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" ? I know I can do it via dealing with mere string without involving dateFormatter and NSDate, but won't such solution be vulnerable? Please advice me what's the simplest(and robust) way to deal with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You won't be able to parse an `NSDate` object from a string unless your formatter matches the input format. You have set up your formatter to use `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` as the format, but then later you say the format of the string is actually `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have your formatter wrong...

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
var output = formatter.dateFromString("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
```

After that, you can get the hour component with

```
if let date = output {
    var hours = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.HourCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but NSCalendar evaluates to 1 instead of 12.00, are you sure it gets the hour component?

Comment: alright, works now thanks! but last question, how to retrieve hours with minutes? So i can obtain 6.30 for instace

Comment: or nevermind, I guess I can get minutes and concatenate with hours :)

Comment: Well, I noticed one problem; when I use .MinuteCalendarUnit, for 07 the result is 7 instead of 07. How to format it? @marcos-crispino